# Windows 2012 R2 AD LDS Restore to another computer

Tags: active-directory, restore

I've been having trouble restoring an instance of AD LDS from one computer to another following the Microsoft technet instructions. For the same server installed with the same windows restore image it is fine, but when restoring to another server build, it will fail for me.

I've tried creating a test LDS instance on server1 and I'd like to move it over to server2. (The use case is that server1 has an imminent hardware failure).

I've tried both Windows Server Backup and a backup done through dsdbutil with the create full command on the AD LDS test instance. Both result in the same issue.

Server2 is created in the exact same way as Server1.
As per technet article, technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770886 and technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770886(v=ws.10).aspx
I stop the directory, delete everything in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft ADAM\instance_name\data

I copy my backed up adamntds.dit to the above folder (or have Windows Server backup do it for me) and start the directory back up.
I encounter:

[Operation failed. Error code: 0x8000500d
The directory property cannot be found in the cache.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCJkv.png)

Please note, that I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 instead of Windows Server 2008.

I'm pretty sure it is a permissions problem.
When I set up the LDS instance, I used the [Network Service Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPvhx.png)

Run AD LDS using the following account:NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

Set up the following account to administer AD LDS:WIN-6B9R4ROQ36T\Administrator
I've tried giving all permissions to both the administrator account and the network service account. I've even added the network service account to Administrators group. Nothing seems to work...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason only is hardware failure, you could also create a vhdx from server 1 with disk2vhd (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)

and then write it to the disk of server2 (https://superuser.com/questions/40294/copying-a-vhd-to-a-physical-disk)

or boot from vhdx (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825691.aspx)

or you could simply run the vhdx as a VM in Hyper-V

Advantages: You have exactly the same settings on server2 which you had on server1. You have many possibilities to do something with your vhdx like running as a VM.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, the suggestion is to create a VM, write the contents of my failing server over to the VM and then move that VM to another server. Because of the hardware abstraction of a VM, it will be portable to another server of different underlying hardware?

If that is the case, then this might probably work. I'll look into this solution, but ideally, I'd like to just migrate the AD LDS instance. I think I've narrowed it down to a permissions issue, but can't get over the last hurdle.

Comment: I found the solution!! Thank you for your reply, this is definitely a good avenue to look at. Basically, to resolve this issue with just LDS, you must add within the directory, specific permissions to allow the administrator group in CN=Administrators. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!! Thank you for your reply, this is definitely a good avenue to look at. Basically, to resolve this issue with just LDS, you must add within the directory, specific permissions to allow the administrator group in CN=Administrators. Thanks again